# What's the best way to keep insects from coming in Jalousie windows?

Tags: windows, screens, insect

My house has an attached sunroom with old [Jalousie windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jalousie_window). They're great for a breeze, but I'd like to find a way to keep insects from coming through.

What are my options (other than replacing them)? Is it possible to attach screening to them, for example?

I've contacted several places that make windows and screens, and no one seems to know how to make screens for these windows. It sounds like no one has ever asked them before.

Comment: It looks like at least some [come with screens](http://interior.kichikennel.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/How-To-Replace-Jalousie-Windows.jpg).  I guess if the axis of rotation is towards the middle this wouldn't work.  The ones in the picture seem to rotate out only.  I guess screens inside isn't an option for you?

Comment: May be possible to mount a screen; depends on the exact design. Another option would be to let the bugs into the sunroom (poissibly with a bug zapper to keep them under control) but put screening on the door/windows between it and the rest of the house.

Answer (score 3):

Window screens usually go on the inside of jalousie windows because (most) jalousie windows open outward (at least partly).

If you want to install a screen on the outside then you would (probably) need to build a frame around the window, with enough depth so that the window will not touch the outside screen. Also, you will probably need to weather-proof an exterior frame (like with flashing), depending on the depth and overhang of the eve.

Installing a screen on the inside may be easier, but ease of screen removal and durability with respect to repetetive screen removal (like for cleaning dead bugs) should be considered in the design.

Answer (score 0):

A screen mesh curtain is what my mother-in-law uses on her windows. It is fairly inexpensive and very easy to remove for cleaning.

[image]

It can be found on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01I54IZMC) for $10 per 2 pack.